# Glass material "muddens" material below it in cycles

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

I'm trying to do a render of a wristwatch, I'm not sure what happened, but somewhere along the line when I'm texturing the model, especially the dial part, the problem starts showing up.

This is the issue in question:
[image: glass "muddy"]

As you can see, the dial looks muddy, blurry, and it only happens when the glass is active on top of it. Now, this is the one without the glass:

[image: no glass]

Without the glass, it looks crisp, I tried changing light positions, problem still persists, it only shows up when the glass is on top of it.

This is the nodes I use for my glass material:

[image: glass node]

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Before it happens, I'm using anisotropic shader with radial tangent for the "sunburst" effect, but the glass makes the whole dial muddy, I read some solution in this site that the denoise kinda messes up anisotropic, so I changed the whole dial to use texture instead, but the problem still persists.

Another info:
Denoise on, samples 128
My laptop specs are quite old, it's i7 3630QM, 16gb ram, GT650M 2GB (it's ancient). Is this actually simple to solve, or my laptop just not capable for the fix?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using denoising? Denoising usually doesn't work as well for refractive materials such as glass.

Comment: This is most likely denoising artifacts. Try increasing the number of samples

Comment: It's the denoising. The denoising is quite good, but especially glass materials produce a lot of noise, so with a very low sample rate like 128 the denoising artifacts become much more visible. By the way, is there a good reason why you use this material setup with 6 nodes to create glass instead of simply taking 1 _Glass BSDF_ node? Or maybe a _Principled BSDF_ set to _Transmission_ = 1?

Comment: I see, so the denoise is the one producing this, thank you everyone, I'll try to increase number of samples, or just render them separately if possible...

@GordonBrinkmann I'm copying some tutorials for glass, the method you write looks better, I'll try it, thank you!

Comment: I agree - use a simple Glass BSDF and maybe bring the IOR down closer to 1 (but not exactly 1 - exactly 1 is zero refraction. )